# How to cook right a DataStax accessor with sync and async methods?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

When I write an [accessor](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/common/drivers/reference/accessorAnnotatedInterfaces.html) for an entity I usually add sync and async versions of the same query. For example:

```
@Accessor
public interface SourceDataAccessor {
      @Query("select * from source_data where data_id = ?")
      Result<SourceDataCass> get(UUID dataId);

      @Query("select * from source_data where data_id = ?")
      ListenableFuture<Result<SourceDataCass>> getAsync(UUID dataId);
}
```

But when the accessor is instantiated warnings like that appear in the log:

```
12:32:49,793  WARN com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster:2109 - Re-preparing already prepared query select * from source_data where data_id = ?. Please note that preparing the same query more than once is generally an anti-pattern and will likely affect performance. Consider preparing the statement only once.
```

May be there is a way to have both sync and async versions of the same query but without re-preparing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the accessor to return a `Statement`.

```
@Accessor
public interface SourceDataAccessor {
  @Query("select * from source_data where data_id = ?")
  Statement get(UUID dataId);
}
```

and then execute the Statement using

```
ResultSet rs = session.execute(statement);
```

or

```
ResultSetFuture rsf = session.executeAsync(statement);
```

For mapping the ResultSet to your class you can then use a Mapper

```
MappingManager mappingManager = new MappingManager(session);
Mapper mapper = mappingManager.mapper(SourceDataCass.class);
Result<SourceDataClass> sourceDataClass = mapper.map(rs);
```

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting use case.

Currently we don't support it, so the workaround would be to write the accessor with only the async method, and then use `getAsync().getUninterruptibly()` as the sync version (that's how it's done internally). I agree that it's not very user-friendly, you could use a wrapper class to do it, but that's still an extra step.

One thing we could do pretty easily is cache the prepared statements when we process the methods, so at least it would not prepare twice when a query is repeated within the same interface.

Please open a [JIRA ticket](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/projects/JAVA) if you're interested to see this in the driver. If you feel like fixing it yourself, you can also create a pull request (from a quick look, the only method to change is [AccessorMapper#prepare](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.0/driver-mapping/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/mapping/AccessorMapper.java#L37)).

Comment: Thanks Oliver! I hope I'll find a time to create the pull request.